# c++ openmp shared_ptr datarace

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a c++ program where I try to use openmp on a for loop. The for loop works with an shared_ptr to my own class that in turn calls another dll. I get errors:

> Table 7. Current pointer and in_use_count are inconsistent.

The code looks something like this..

```
    int n = 1000;
    std::vector<double> result(n),indata(n);

    // populate indata

    std::shared_ptr<MyNS::MyClass> sp_mycl = std::make_shared < MyNS::MyClass >();
    sp_mycl->var1 = 2;
    // populate sp_mycl->v_var4
    #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(sp_mycl)
    for (auto ii = 0; ii<n;ii++)
    {
        sp_mycl->var2 = indata[ii];
        sp_mycl->calc();
        result[ii] = sp_mycl->var3;
    }
```

and MyClass.h looks similar to this

```
namespace MyNS
{
    extern "C" { double * fortran_dll_calc(int *num, double arrinput[],double arroutput[])} // subroutine in fortran dll
    class MyClass
    {
        double var1, var2, var3;
        std::vector<double> v_var4;
        void calc();
    }
}
```

and MyClass.cpp

```
using namespace MyNS;
void MyClass::calc()
{
    int len = v_var4.size();
    double *test = new double[len];
    for (auto is = 0; is<len;is++)
        test[is] = v_var4[is];
    double fortran_result[10]; // output from fortran dll 
    fortran_dll_calc(len,test,fortran_result);
    for (int ir = 0;ir < 10;ir++)
        var3 += fortran_result[ir];
}
```

I use MSVS with Intel parallel studio c++/fortran compiler 2016.

I want the `sp_mycl->var1` to have the same inital value for all threads, hence the firstprivate for `sp_mycl`.

The openmp for loop seems to be going wrong somewhere, and when debugging it sometimes appear to stop inside `MyClass::calc()`, and sometimes already at `sp_mycl->var2= indata[ii]`. This much I have found out using some `cout` outputs.

Is the `firstprivate` working with `shared_ptr` to my own defined objects?
I am a beginner thus, there might be many mistakes and errors, any comment on anything in the code is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OpenMP is going to initialize the private version of `sp_mycl` for each of the thread as follows:

```
   auto priv_sp_mycl = sp_mycl;
```

This is done in parallel and invokes the copy constructor which needs finally needs to update the reference counting for the `shared_ptr`. However, `shared_ptr` implementation in STL is not thread-safe so there is where things starts to goes wrong.

However, I am not sure this is what you want. Why do you want to have every thread pointing to the same object? Wouldn't that introduce an additional race condition into your program? Also each thread is writing the result into `result[n]`... did you mean `result[ii]`?

Anyway, I think this is what you want:

```
MyNS::MyClass sp_mycl;
sp_mycl.var1 = 2;
// populate sp_mycl->v_var4
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(sp_mycl)
for (auto ii = 0; ii<n;ii++)
{
    sp_mycl.var2 = indata[ii];
    sp_mycl.calc();
    result[ii] = sp_mycl.var3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  @simple01. The only thing I wonder is if it is dangerous to put a lot of objects on the stack??

Comment: Each thread has a separate stack... and you only put one `MyClass` object each which is `3*sizeof(double) + sizeof(std::vector)` which is around 200 bytes (keep in mind std::vector does memory allocation on the heap and not the stack). I think stack usage is not an issue here.